# Asking for non-brand specific tool qualities- on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

I am looking for a drill press... but I don't want a recommendation for a specific drill press. Instead, I want to know what **qualities** are important to consider while buying a drill press. I would then choose the drill press based on the most upvoted quality, and descending down the list.

An example quality could look like this:

---

## Work Light

A work light is important to get on a drill press because it allows you to see what you are doing with greater detail. Among other things, a work light can also help make more precise holes in material. Because it is sometimes dim under the top of the drill press, these lights come in handy often.

---

This question would be in the vein of [What to look for in buying laminate flooring](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2126/what-to-look-for-in-buying-laminate-flooring?rq=1) and [What are the things to look out for when buying a motion detector?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14240/what-are-the-things-to-look-out-for-when-buying-a-motion-detector) and especially [What to look for when buying recessed lights?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6969/what-to-look-for-when-buying-recessed-lights?rq=1)

Is this on-topic? I feel like solid answers for questions like these could be immensely helpful and in the spirit of SE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me this would invite a lot of subjective answers.

Comment: That's right, but the votes on each answer will determine whether the answer is practical or impractical in terms of answering the question.

Comment: I also edited the question above to include some examples of questions that would be similar to mine.

Comment: I think poll type questions are off topic on all SE sites.

Comment: That's what I thought. I just noticed that it seems like this site had more relaxed standards than most, so I was wondering if this sort of question would be acceptable. I'll instead go ask around on a forum. Thanks.